# Parallel vector multiplication using several threads takes longer than sequential

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have two functions, which do the multiplication of two vectors of integers (filled with all ones for now). I expect the function `vector_multiplication_concurrent`, which uses threads to be faster than the function `vector_multiplication`. However, it is actually a bit slower. I suspect that this is because only one thread works on `result` variable at a time, so the threads do not actually do the job in parallel. Is it correct? How should I change the code to get the parallel function to be faster?

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

void vector_multiplication(std::vector<int> const & v1,
                           std::vector<int> const & v2,
                           int & result) {

    for (int ind = 0; ind < v1.size(); ++ind) {
        result += v1[ind] * v2[ind];
    }

}

static std::mutex mtx;
void vector_multiplication_concurrent(std::vector<int> const & v1,
                                     std::vector<int> const & v2,
                                     int start_ind, int end_ind,
                                     int & result) {


    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx);

    for (int ind = start_ind; ind <= end_ind; ++ind) {
        result += v1[ind] * v2[ind];
    }

}

int main(){

    std::vector<int> v1 (10000000, 1);
    std::vector<int> v2 (10000000, 1);

    int result = 0;

    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    vector_multiplication(v1, v2, result);
    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto duration = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t2 - t1).count();
    std::cout << "Duration: " << duration << '\n';
    std::cout << "Product: " << result << '\n';


    int result_concurrent = 0;
    int threads_num = 4;
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;

    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t3 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (int th = 0; th < threads_num; ++th) {
        threads.push_back(std::thread(vector_multiplication_concurrent,
                                      std::ref(v1),
                                      std::ref(v2),
                                      th * (v1.size() / threads_num),
                                      th * (v1.size() / threads_num) + v1.size() / threads_num - 1,
                                      std::ref(result_concurrent)));
    }
    for (auto & th : threads) {
        th.join();
    }

    std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t4 = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto duration_concurrent = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t4 - t3).count();
    std::cout << "Duration concurrent: " << duration_concurrent << '\n';
    std::cout << "Product concurrent: " << result_concurrent << '\n';


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your concurrent task locks the global mutex for it's entire duration so it's not possible for two threads to work at the same time. This is a single thread algorithm with a lot of extra overhead run sequentially by a variety of threads.

Comment: If you lock a mutex for the entire time the function is running then it is not a concurrent function.  It's thread safe, but will never run in parallel.

Comment: if you are only concurrently reading from the vector you dont need the mutex, race conditions only appear if at least one thread is writing

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, so is there a way to make it parallel? Can I use some temporary result variables, which are calculated in parallel and then add them?

Comment: @user463035818, if I don't use mutex, the result is wrong.

Comment: yes my comment was incomplete, see the answer

Comment: @user_185051 Exactly. Make each calculation self contained and merge the results outside of the concurrent portion.

Comment: Create a `local_result` variable to use in the `for` loop. Then use mutex to add to the `result`. Better yet, since it is an int, just use `std::atomic` for the type of the `result`.

Comment: You may find `std::async` easier to use for this purpose.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux, thanks, I will look into it. I am just starting with threads and wanted to understand how `std::thread` works.

Comment: @ilya1725, thank you, this is what I was thinking of doing, but couldn't figure out how to implement it exactly. I will look into `std::atomic`, but wanted to first understand how `std::thread` works.

Comment: Note that `std::atomic` is not free, it has some performance overhead.  So use them judiciously and with forethought.  On my system, a regular int is about x40 faster than an `std:atomic` int.  (Your mileage may vary, depending on your platform.)

Comment: @user_185051: Using `std::atomic` instead of direct `std::mutex` will make the code easier and maybe faster. However, the main key is to use the algorithm in the accepted answer - initial calculation in a temporary, non-atomic, variable. Also, playing around with the number of threads can provide benefits, but it is architecture dependent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in comments you are locking the mutex for the whole duration of the function, hence the code is actually sequential. 
You only need a mutex if several threads access the same memory and at least one is writing.

In case of summing vector elements you only need to have several threads writing to the same memory when adding the final result, hence you can change the function to:

```
static std::mutex mtx;
void vector_multiplication_concurrent(std::vector<int> const & v1,
                                     std::vector<int> const & v2,
                                     int start_ind, int end_ind,
                                     int & result) {

    // fully parallel part
    // v1 and v2 are shared, but you are only reading
    int temp = 0;

    for (int ind = start_ind; ind <= end_ind; ++ind) {
        temp += v1[ind] * v2[ind];
    }
    // only this requires you to synchronize access 
    // result is shared and you are writing to it
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
    result += temp;
}
```

PS: I would strongly suggest you to use iterators instead of indexes. Also note that your loop is basically a rewrite of [`std::inner_product`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product). Using that instead of the plain loop will make your code more expressive.